# A good practice to create phalcon 2.0 form decorators?

Tags: php, html, forms, decorator, phalcon

To created form decorators (for view rendering), I have created an abstract class **BaseForm** as follows:

```
abstract class BaseForm extends Form {

/**
 * Render form field
 * @param $name
 * @param array $attr
 * @return string
 */
public function renderDecorated($name, $attr = [])
{
    $e = $this->get($name);
    return '<li '.($this->hasErrors($e)?'class="error"':'').'>'.$this->renderItem($e, $attr).'</li>';
}

/**
 * Render form field with errors displayed
 * @param $name
 * @param array $attr
 * @return string
 */
public function renderDecoratedErrors($name, $attr = [])
{
    $e = $this->get($name);
    return '<li '.($this->hasErrors($e)?'class="error"':'').'>'.$this->renderErrors($e).$this->renderItem($e, $attr).'</li>';
}

/**
 * Render classic form field
 * @param $e
 * @param array $attr
 * @return string
 */
public function renderItem($e, $attr = []){
    return '<label for="'.$e->getName().'">'.$e->getLabel().'</label>'.$e->render($attr);
}

/**
 * Render errors
 * @param $e
 * @return string
 */
public function renderFieldErrors($e){
    $m = $this->getMessagesFor($e->getName());
    if (count($m)) {
        $r = '<ul class="err_msg">';
        foreach ($m as $i) {
            $r .= '<li>'.$this->flash->error($i).'</li>';
        }
        return $r.'</ul>';
    }
}

/**
 * Check if specific field by $e has assigned errors
 * @param $e
 * @return bool
 */
public function hasErrors($e){
    $m = $this->getMessagesFor($e->getName());
    if (count($m))
        return true;
    return false;
}

/**
 * Decorator for form errors
 * @return null|string
 */
public function renderErrorsDecorated(){
    if(count($this->getMessages())){
        $r = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>';
        foreach ($this->getMessages() as $key => $message) {
            $r .= $message. '<br />';
        }
        return $r.'</div>';
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

All of my forms should extend **BaseForm** class. All of **BaseForm** methods are usually called only in views.

A sample of usage can be found here: https://github.com/mpetcu/report-manager/tree/master/app/forms

Is there another way to do it? I don't think using view logic (HTML) in form classes is the right way?

Comment: Take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/tree/master/phalcon/forms).
I think the Phalcon way is to use HTML in the element classes not in the form class.

Comment: I refer to the HTML that covers an element and to hepls in design of a form in a list or table of elements. Element itself should be me managed seoaratly.